# Use preprocessor to "remove" prefix from function in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I write a framework with lot of function that are named like that :
ICE_ModuleType_FunctionUse()
and everything else have ICE_ prefix (typename, define etc...)

And with preprocessor I would like to remove ICE_ to reduce function name lenght when the user know there is no conflict with other libs.

But the only working way I found was to write every function, type etc... by hand like that :

```
#define ModuleType_FunctionUse ICE_ModuleType_FunctionUse
```

Any Idea on how to easly do that ?

Comment: Please explain the reason for what you want to do. It seems that the easiest way to go is to actually **not** do it. What is the disadvantage of having that prefix? Speed of typing? Space in storage?

Comment: @Yunnosch To remove ICE_ to reduce function name lenght when the user know there is no conflict with other libs.

Comment: well, this is kind of "manual namespacing" and you want something similar to importing a namespace. The preprocessor can do it, the way you already describe it yourself. Wrap all these defines in an `#ifdef IMPORT_ICE` and you're done. But there's no better way. The only thing you could do is write a tool generating all these `#define`s from the existing headers.

Comment: There isn’t a simple way (nor, as far as I can deduce, a complicated way) to shorten names systematically using the C preprocessor.  Extending is easy and routine; shortening is not.  Your given reason for wanting to do it isn’t all that compelling.  I think an appropriate scripting language (e.g. Perl or Python) to systematically edit long identifiers into shorter ones is your best hope. One advantage is that the job is done once and finished rather than being done on every compilation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "*Your given reason for wanting to do it isn’t all that compelling.*" <- well, if you consequently work with namespaces, "importing" one is a nice little feature. It's just questionable it's worth the hassle needed to do this in C, which doesn't support (custom) namespaces. If I'd want to do it anyways, I'd probably go for a tool that automates the creation of the `#define`s in the build process...

Answer (score 2):

You could automatically create a new header file with a name like `use_namespace_ICE.h` for your clients to use. This file would have the required list of `#defines`, and can be generated using the utilities `nm` or `dumpbin` applied to your library.

For example, if `foo.c` is:

```
void ICE_ModuleType_FunctionUse(void) { /* code */ }
```

then:

```
cc -c -o foo.o foo.c
nm foo.o | grep ' T _ICE_' | sed 's/.* T _ICE_\(.*\)/#define \1 ICE_\1/'
```

yields:

```
#define ModuleType_FunctionUse ICE_ModuleType_FunctionUse
```

Comment: **Edit:** This was tested using Cygwin. For Linux, remove the leading underscore. That is, change the two instances of `_ICE_` to `ICE_`.

Comment: I'd probably go for a source-based tool, e.g. to avoid the platform dependency ... but nice idea anyways, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments tell you, there is no way, or no easy way, to *shorten* identifiers once written in your source code. However, you can reduce the typing for things that still need to be written:

```
#define ModuleType_FunctionUse ICE_ModuleType_FunctionUse
```

This defines that the short name will be replaced with the longer name.